# How to use the partial in zendframework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, partials, view-helpers

In ZF1 we use partial in layout.phtml file something like that

```
$this->partial('header.phtml', array('vr' => 'zf2'));
```

How we can do the same in ZF2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this can be achieved by

```
 echo $this->partial('layout/header', array('vr' => 'zf2'));
```

you can access the variable in view using

```
echo $this->vr;
```

don't forget to add following line in your view_manager of module.config.php file.

```
'layout/header'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
```

after adding it looks like this

```
return array(  

'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view' ,
        ),
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',

            'layout/header'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',            

            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),


    ),    

);
```

Comment: To pass all the view variables to the partial:
`echo $this->partial('layout/header',$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables());`

Comment: Note that `$this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables()` returns an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

Comment: To merge additionnal data, array_merge works : echo $this->partial('mypartial', array_merge($this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getVariables(), [moredata]));

Answer (score 6):

As already stated in the accepted answer, you can use

```
echo $this->partial('layout/header', array('vr' => 'zf2'));
```

but then you have to define `layout/header` in your module.config.php.

---

If you don't want to clutter your `template_map`, you can use a relative path based on `template_path_stack` to point to your partial directly.

Suppose you defined:

```
'view_manager' => array(
        /* [...] */
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view' ,
        ),
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',

            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
    ),    
);
```

in your module.config.php and your listsnippet.phtml lies in `.../view/mycontroller/snippets/listsnippet.phtml`, then you can use following code:

```
echo $this->partial('mycontroller/snippets/listsnippet.phtml', array('key' => 'value'));
```