# zend 2 -using Zend Forms in partial view helper

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I have a form that is repeated over several different modules.

I would like to avoid repeating the same process over and over again and want to render the form once (in my application module)  and then simply use a partial view script to call it wherever I wish like this;

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partialLayout/advertForm'); ?>
```

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180081/how-to-use-the-partial-in-zendframework2) it would be pretty straightforward to do this if I simply created a HTML form in the partial script and then called it.

However, I want to use Zend Forms. Bearing in mind that zend form are loaded onto the page via the controller- how do I get around this.

i guess that the crux of the question is - how do you call a Zend Form in another module using a partial view script.

Comment: You can achieve this using the `forward` plugin; I have [another answer that shows an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533751/zf2-widgets-views-in-layout/25535518#25535518). Essentially you would have one controller action that just renders the form as normal and any controller that needs to include the form can call that.

Comment: thanks AlexPs, novel solution. i will however opt for Alain P solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that with a ViewHelper. My solution [is posted here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=129123&sid=4cc96933897a7f97eb2f1c91d6403beb), in Zend Forums.

There it is.

**The code ViewHelper :**

```
<?php
/**
* View helper to return the HTML code of the login form. 
*
* @filesource LoginForm.php
* @encodage UTF-8
* @author DAFAP Informatique - Alain Pomirol
* @date 10 nov. 2015
* @version 2015-1
*/
namespace Login\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Login\Form\LoginForm as Formulaire;

class LoginForm extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

  protected $sm;

  public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
    $this->sm = $serviceLocator;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getServiceLocator()
  {
    return $this->sm;
  }

  public function __invoke()
  {
    $form = new Formulaire();
    $layout = new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
    $viewRender = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
    $layout->setTemplate('login/index/index.phtml');
    return $viewRender->render($layout);
  }
}
```

**The statement in *module.config.php* in Login module :**

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'loginForm' => 'Login\View\Helper\LoginForm'
    )
),
```

**Use in view of the application module :**

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'loginForm' => 'Login\View\Helper\LoginForm'
    )
),
```

Comment: hello Alain. thank for the advice. i will try it out

Comment: hI Alain- your solution is perfect. do you think you could post the actual code here so that i can mark it as the acceptable answer.it would really help other searchers if they could see the actual code rather than following a link to another site

Comment: I just publish it. Delighted to have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem!  *Forms can really be a slow-down with ZF2.*

I use Twig (recommended) but you can port this approach to plain old ZF2 templates too.

Here's one such template I use nearly everywhere:

**horizontal_form.twig**

```
{# render rows only, not the form tag #}
{% do form.prepare() %}
{% for f in form %}
    {% do f.setOption( 'twb-layout', 'horizontal' ) %}
    {{  formRow( f ) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've got a second with a slightly different approach to support a specific IdentifiableForm in my code:

**identifiable_form.twig**

```
<form id="{{ form.getAttribute('name') }}" name="{{ form.getAttribute('name') }}" action="{{ form.getAttribute('action') }}" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="class" value="{{ form.getAttribute('class') }}">
    {% for f in form %}
        {% do f.setOption( 'twb-layout', 'horizontal' ) %}
        {% do f.setOption( 'twb-form-group-size', 'form-group-sm' ) %}
        {{ formRow( f ) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-right">Save</button>
</form>
```

With those two in the pocket, my usage looks like this:

**In a twig template that should use a form**

...include the template from the other:

```
<div class="panel-body">

    {% set form = general_config_form %}
    {% do form.prepare() %}
    {% include 'application/generic/identifiable_form' %}

</div>
```

The controller action that operates that template looks like:

```
$vm = new ViewModel();
$vm->setTerminal( true );
$vm->setTemplate( 'application/admin/config/index' );

$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$fm = $sm->get( 'FormElementManager' );

$country = $config_mapper->get('general.country', true );
$general_config_form = $fm->get( GeneralConfigForm::class, [ 'country' => $country ] );
$general_config_form->setAttribute('action', '/admin-config/form-save' );
$vm->setVariable( 'general_config_form', $general_config_form );
```

In the end it's just a game of:

- instantiating/loading the form in the action
- setting the form as a variable in the ViewModel
- including the "generic form template" from that action's actual template

On topic, if you hate rigging forms as much as I do, I made a little tool to save time here: https://github.com/Saeven/zf2-circlical-formtool

Second, if you use Bootstrap in your app, this form helper replacement really makes things look nice: https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Saeven. thank you so much for your ideas. i will indeed look into it futher.